# Is there a way to control the number of threads used with pmap?

Tags: clojure

I am just doing some performance testing with clojure using pmap and I would like to be able to control the number of threads being used with pmap. I know when using something like OpenMP one can set the number of threads using omp_set_num_threads(). I was wondering if there would be anything similar in clojure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's code for `pmap`:

```
(defn pmap
  "Like map, except f is applied in parallel. Semi-lazy in that the
  parallel computation stays ahead of the consumption, but doesn't
  realize the entire result unless required. Only useful for
  computationally intensive functions where the time of f dominates
  the coordination overhead."
  ([f coll]
   (let [n (+ 2 (.. Runtime getRuntime availableProcessors))
         rets (map #(future (f %)) coll)
         step (fn step [[x & xs :as vs] fs]
                (lazy-seq
                 (if-let [s (seq fs)]
                   (cons (deref x) (step xs (rest s)))
                   (map deref vs))))]
     (step rets (drop n rets))))
```

As you can see, `pmap` takes **all available processors** and uses them cyclically. So, no, there's no way to set the number of threads... but you can always write your own `pmap`, which will provide such functionality.